# When using offline compression with django-compressor, how can I add support for multiple deployment stages (prod, qa, test) with CDN?

Tags: django, django-compressor

I have a very simple setup for a django application which gets packaged in jenkins where it runs offline compression with django-compressor, runs integration tests and then deployes to a QA server.
Later i would have a job which uses the same package to deploy on our prod server.

This all works good and well as long as resource paths are the same on all three stages - but i would now like to add a CDN for static resources which simply proxies the requests on prod server, which means i need another URL prefix (MEDIA_URL) for production. Currently when i simply change my packaging to point the MEDIA_URL to the CDN my integration tests fail and the QA server is broken, because the CDN proxies the production server.. So i would like to keep using relativ non prefixed paths for integration and customize the URL prefix to the compressed media files with a remote URL.

Is there any sane way to do this? for my integration tests i could imagine i simply create a /etc/hosts entry to point the CDN host name to the test server, but this seems like an ugly workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably set up a separate CDN instance for each environment. I do this using Amazon S3, it's easy to create new buckets for each environment.